# Write a python program that gives me every year from 1583 to 2017 where new year is a Monday and x-mas (24.12) is not

Tags: python, datetime

I want to write a python program that gives me every year from 1583 to 2017 where new years day (1.1.) is a Monday and X-mas (24.12) is not. I want to do it with the use of datetime.

I have already tried something but as I am new to python and do not know the datetime module very well, i did not come up with a solution

```
import calendar

def is_ny_monday_while_xmas_not(date,weekday):
    if (calendar.weekday(date.year, date.month, 1) == "Monday":
```

the output should look like :
1684
1846
1934
...
(I do not know the right years so this is just an example)

Comment: Do you need to check christmas of same year or previos year (closest one)?

Comment: It should be the same year.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's pretty straitforward

```
from datetime import date

for year in range(1583, 2018):
  if date(year, 1, 1).weekday() == 0 and date(year, 12, 24).weekday() != 0:
    print(year)
```

Mention the end of range, which I've changed from 2017 to 2018 to because 'stop' not included in enumeration (but it isn't changed anything cause it's not Monday).

Good optimization from another answer (mention 4 as the third parameter to range()) but beware to copypaste it into another check conditions.

```
from datetime import date

for year in range(1584, 2018, 4):
  if date(year, 1, 1).weekday() == 0 and date(year, 12, 24).weekday() != 0:
    print(year)
```

Comment: Note that `weekday()` gives you the days starting from 0, meaning monday is 0, not 1.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have tried it for hours. But may I ask you for what is the 1,1 after the year in the if statement?

Comment: @besch150 ```date(year, 1, 1)``` is the date with year=year, month=1, day=1, i.e. NY, guess what is ```date(year, 12, 24)``` :)

Comment: @besch150 `if date(year, 1, 1).weekday()` means to check for year `year`, month `1` (January) and day `1`. So, the 1st of January for that year.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there are 357 days between 1 Jan and 24 Dec on a year that isn't a leap year, and 357 is divisible by 7. This means that if January 1 is a Monday, December 24 also is. Therefore, the question is equivalent to: what years are leap years and also start with a Monday?

```
from datetime import date
year = 1584 #first leap year after 1583
while year < 2017:
    if date(year, 1, 1).weekday() == 0:
        if year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0 #years that are divisible by 100 aren't leap years, unless divisible by 400.
        print(year)
    year += 4
```

This should print out all years you need.

Comment: NEVER implement your own calendaring. There are so many exceptions it's impossible.

Comment: @LtWorf How so? I don't see how there would be many exceptions here. If there were, it's not difficult to check the 24th Dec as well or use a library to find leap years, but that would be unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Because in that many years they probably changed calendar method, added days and various fuckery.

Comment: @LtWorf I assume you mean the switch from the Julian to Gregorian calendar. Either that is picked up by the datetime lib itself and isn't a problem, or it is a problem and wouldn't work regardless of whether your own calendaring was implemented

Comment: @LtWorf Yeah, no. Timezones have no effect here. The OP simply wants a date. Timezones don't affect what year becomes a leap year or not.

Comment: Got to watch it all, there are so many gotchas, not like he listed them all. Use a library :P

Comment: @LtWorf Wow, nice evidence there. I've seen that video years ago. Nothing in there that would stop this from working. If there was an event that would stop this from working, it would break the `datetime` library itself - or the library has accomodated for it and therefore this code works. It is just impossible for this to be a negative solution to the problem.

If you can somehow miraculously find a way that this would break only when looking at leap years manually, it'd be nice for you to actually provide proof rather than asking to "use a library" LOL. I'm not your fact checker.